# PhP fopen creates file with Path name

Tags: php

Trying to update a file **file.xml**, which is with folders **dirA/dirB/dirC/file.xml** where **dirA** is the current working dir. The file file.xml exists and has write permissions.

Using the following code works in local but on server it created a file by name "dirA\dirB\dirC\file.xml" outside dirA and saves into it

```
$file = fopen("dirA\dirB\dirC\file.xml", "w+")
fputs($file, $xmlFile);
fclose($file);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: try $file = fopen("dirB/dirC/file.xml", "w+")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are running another environment on your server?
Windows and Linux are a little bit itchy on their folders.

You may also check if you have to use backslashes or not!

Probably you also have to quote them:

```
$file = fopen("dirA\/dirB\/dirC\/file.xml", "w+");
```

Comment: Thanks, your right my system is win and server linux but dint think of this.